# What is the probability that any two students had atleast one county in common?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, data-analysis

There are 20 students in class and each student was asked to give a chart for 10 different counties in the state of Texas.
Here in the state of Texas, there are 254 counties

So what I am doing here is basically using combinations to find the counties such that there are not any common for that I am going with.

C(254,10) * C(244,10) * C(234,10) ....so on till * C(64,10) / C(254,10)^20

is this the approach correct or any other suggestions?

Comment: Two particular students or any two?

Comment: Any two students

Comment: @MathLover what if it asked that There are 20 students in class and each student was asked to give a chart for 10 different counties in the state of Texas.  What is the probability that a given two students had all of the same counties?

Comment: Do be careful with how you define your denominator!

Comment: @MathLover That I did but I have one more question where I am asked 

There are 20 students in class and each student was asked to give a chart for 10 different counties in the state of Texas. What is the probability that at least 25% of the counties had a chart turned in?

Total 254 counties 25% is 64 counties

Comment: We cannot keep doing this in comments. You need to be clear what your question is and post your question saying what you did and which part you need help with.

Comment: @MathLover sorry for that I have updated my question up here 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3827406/what-is-the-probability-that-a-given-two-students-had-all-of-the-same-counties